# Qt quick 2 alternative for table view

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qtquick2

I have a program on qt quick2.
So, I need a table representation of some data in my program, but qt quick since version 2 doesn't have table view. What is the easiest way (or simple alternatives) to achieve a similar behaviour as a table view in qt quick 2?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Seriously: vertical-scroll QML ListView: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#orientation-prop with specific delegate which can be any kind of row. There examples on the Net. One of simplest is QML GridView but more suitable for left-to-right / top-to-bottom type of fill with cells of same size. But I did use it for kind of table with all cells of same type and the row of fixed number of items. It is easy but may not satisfy your request.

Comment: Wait, wait ... what about [TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html)?

Comment: @folibis That's for qt quick 1, not for qt quick 2.

Comment: Do you mean Qt Quick Controls 2? `TableView - Since: Qt 5.1` and that's  Qt Quick 2. Anyway there is no another widget so why not just use it?

Comment: @folibis `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4` It's not QT Quick 2.

Comment: Exactly. But you noticed you use `quick2`. So you have to clarify the question.